# Automatic variable creation when adding new instance of a class

Tags: python

I am teaching my self Python, and I am getting my head around OOP classes. I keep seeing examples like this.

```
import ClassImade

var1 = ClassImade()
Var2 = ClassImade()
```

The program I am trying to make will have several thousand instances of the class. My question is: how has this issue been over come? I have seen in other posts that this is part of bad construction of the program. if that is so why do I keep seeing it over and over again in examples?

Comment: It might be acceptable for one or two instances. If you have "many", you need to use a list, a dict, or some other container that will allow you to programmatically handle multiple variables. Defining variables manually like that is a direct route to hell via `eval/exec`.

Comment: `all_my_instances_in_single_list = [ClassImade() for _ in range(several_thousand)]`?

Comment: I need to be able to isolate each system. If they are all in the same list would it be harder to access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var = []

for i in range(1000):
    var.append(ClassImade())
```

This makes a list of class instances.  Is that what you want?

Comment: `[ClassImade] * 1000` would be much faster, but that does not look like a list of instances but a list of classes.